In the United States, does the amount "Due at Time of Rental" include taxes?
I rented a car in the United States: I booked it online, planning to pick up at the airport. The online booking receipt specifies the amount "Due at Time of Rental":

I wonder the following: In the United States, does the amount "Due at Time of Rental" include taxes? I.e., shall I expect to pay more than the amount "Due at Time of Rental" because of miscellaneous taxes?

The receipt should show all the items charged. Your screenshot only includes the last line of it. What does the full receipt show?

@littleadv here's the part before the total: https://i.sstatic.net/19LHOHF3.png ; https://i.sstatic.net/2fNQbuUM.png

This doesn't look like any reservation confirmation I've ever gotten from any US rental car company (including Hertz). Are you sure you're not being scammed? A receipt should include all the charges properly itemized.

In the US, "subtotal" doesn't include tax, and your "Due at Time of Rental" matches the subtotal....

I suspect butt-covering, so that nobody can claim or sue over miscalculated taxes.

This one is a little strange.
Typically the final quote will include all applicable taxes and fees (of which there are many). In fact one of the more dubious marketing tricks is advertise an artificially low daily rate and than glomp on massive amounts of fees and surcharges.
What's strange in your case is that the daily rate times the days equals the final price. That is generally NOT the way prices are structured in the US and I would expect it to look like this:

It's possible that you are booking from a country where legislation requires Hertz to include all costs in the daily rate.
I would try booking the car through the website and not through an app and see what you get.
US rentals are notorious for aggressive upsells. A good defensive line here is "Sure, I take everything you can give me as long as the final prices is not higher than what it says here on my reservation".
Another one to look out for is insurance. Some credit cards include Collision Damage Waiver (etc) but you may need a letter from the card issuer that you are indeed covered. That is unlikely to happen in the US, but you never know. Most credit cards are used to that nonsense and have a portal where you can get the letter.

Generally yes, that is why it is worded this way. There was probably a push for this because a decade or so ago, prices that were asked at car rentals differed widely from the rate shown during booking.
Even if you have a quote with an 'amount due at time of rental', many companies will try to upsell you some add-ons like insurance, navigation, road-service and tank fill service. They may or may not be pushy about it.
The majority of car rentals will additionally take a deposit to cover extra costs to them, if needed. So, you will need to have more credit available than the amount stated on your receipt. Usually a few days after, they send you a closing statement and balance. If there was damage, fines or insufficient fuel, they will list them on that statement. Also if you returned the car late. Most times, the balance will match what was originally quoted.

Fines may arrive well after the statement.

Right. I've never seen it happen but it would be possible.  Some companies send the final invoice very quickly while others wait, I've gotten some 2 days later all the way to 4 weeks later. I do not know what they would do if the fine was obtain after release of the credit card hold.
